# expkv: Different output depending on a keyword

Tags: key-value, expkv

I need sth. like

`\cmd[map]` ---> "S1 S2 S3"  (output)

`\cmd` ---> "S0" (output) or *equivalently*  `\cmd[map=false]` ---> "S0"  (output)

Is this a key `, boolTF` ?
What do I have to do?

**Wrong MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\ekvdefinekeys{cmd}{
  ,data color = \mycolor
   % .............. ?????
}
\newcommand\cmd[1][]{\begingroup
\ekvset{cmd}{#1}%
\mycolor\color{}%
S1 S2 S3
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\cmd[color=red]
\end{document}
```

Comment: page 4 of the documentation of expkvdef, a few lines before the data handler that you use in your example describes the boolTF prefix.

Comment: Yes, 'boolTF' does not appear in the instructions. However in expkv-def.pdf in both cases I don't understand it.

Comment: The `data` handler is something like a hybrid of `boolTF` and `store`. The storing macro of a `data` handler (so `\mycolor` in your MWE) takes two arguments. As long as the key wasn't used, the second argument of `\mycolor` is executed. After the key was used, the first argument will be executed and the value you passed to the key will be put behind it in braces. So `\mycolor\color{}` will grab both `\color` and `{}`, and insert the second argument (which is empty) if it wasn't used, but after it was used it will input `\color{<value>}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a macro that expands to `S1 S2 S3` if the `map` key was used (and or set to true), and otherwise `S0`.

The easiest way to do it is by using a `boolTF` key which will only accept the values `true` or `false`, and if a value is omitted it uses `true`. The following MWE shows how one could use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expkv}
\usepackage{expkv-def}

\ekvdefinekeys{cmd}{
  ,data color = \mycolor
  ,boolTF map = \mymapTF
}
\newcommand\cmd[1][]
  {%
    \begingroup
    \ekvset{cmd}{#1}%
    \mycolor\color{}%
    \mymapTF{S1 S2 S3}{S0}%
    \endgroup
  }

\begin{document}
\cmd[color=red]

\cmd[map]

\cmd[color=red,map]

\cmd[color=red,map=true]

\cmd[color=red,map=false]
\end{document}
```